# DataFrames not loading in RStudio Viewer

Tags: r, rstudio

I realize that this isn't really a "coding" question per se, but I'm unsure where to direct this question otherwise.  If it violates StackOverflow's rules, I'm happy to move it elsewhere.

Recently, when I View(df), the dataframe pops up as a separate window that looks like this:

[image: Popup data frame]

As opposed to displaying in the Viewer portal in the top panel of RStudio.  Does anyone have any idea why this might be?  I have a vague suspicion that it may be associated with the data.table package, though if so, I am unsure how to avoid this issue.

Thanks

Comment: It's nothing to do with the `data.table` package and I suspect you actually used `View(df)`. Correct caps are important.

Comment: `utils::View(df)` versus rstudio `View` or something, probably. Rstudio writes its own `View` on top of the normal one.

Comment: What version of Rstudio are you using? What version of R? Show the exact code you are running or provide some sort of minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that you can run in a new R session that results in the undesired behavior.

Comment: @Frank, is there any way to have the RStudio View be the preferred function?

Comment: Hm, actually RStudio View already *is* the default. Without a reproducible example, I guess we'll have trouble figuring it out. You could also try https://community.rstudio.com/faq

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I am having trouble figuring out how to even make a reproducible example.  I tried it out on a separate machine and it worked fine, suggesting that it's something due to the options in this particular Markdown file or my computer...

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you are aware, but there is a small button that can pop dataframes into and out of the normal panel. This button pops them out of the normal panel.

[image: Pop DataFrame out of picture]

This button pops them back to the normal panel

[image: Pop DataFame back into normal panel]

What may have happened is you popped the dataframe out of the normal panel, and you have the toolbar not visable. Check your View -> show/hide options to see if there is a toolbar hidden that contains this button.

Comment: Unfortunately, that just pops it in/out of a separate RStudio window.  This seems to be a different issue where the dataframe is not even necessarily displayed in Rstudio.  I'm not sure I'm describing it properly, but your solution does not fix this particular issue.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for the question @elduderino260.  I had the same problem for weeks and it was driving me crazy.

I was able to fix this based on Frank's comment above.  It appears I had imported the `utils` package into my namespace, and the `View()` function in that package overrode the RStudio `View()` function.  The `utils` package apparently has it's own viewer, which is that red and white thing in your screen shot.

So to fix this I removed the reference to `utils` (which I didn't need anyway), regenerated the documentation (which cleared it from the namespace), and restarted the project.  Then everything worked properly.